# javascript replace value from existing key and plus 1 the other keys and values

Tags: javascript

I have an object and i want to replace the value of an existing key and the old value of that key i want to plus 1 the key and also the following other keys plus 1.

So, i want to replace value from key 1 with eee and the old value from key 1 bbb to make a new entry.

How can i achieve this? Any tips?

```
blocks: [
    0: { content: 'aaa'}
    1: { content: 'bbb'}
    2: { content: 'ccc'}
    3: { content: 'ddd'}
]
```

Desired result:

```
blocks: [
    0: { content: 'aaa'}
    1: { content: 'eee'}
    2: { content: 'bbb'}
    3: { content: 'ccc'}
    4: { content: 'ddd'}
]
```

Comment: Is `blocks` an array or object? If its an array then you just need to insert at specified index

Comment: sorry object Satpal

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: If the keys of `blocks` are the same keys as an array and you want to work with it like an array, can you make it an array instead?

Comment: @BenM It's a losing battle, the OP even has almost 2K of rep, I'm not sure how he could not know to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])

```js
var obj = {
  blocks: [
    {content: 'aaa'}, 
    {content: 'bbb'}, 
    {content: 'ccc'}, 
    {content: 'ddd'}
  ]
}

obj.blocks.splice(1, 0, {content: 'eee'})

console.log(obj)
```